# Eigenvalue algorithm for any 3x3 real matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algorithms

I have been looking on the Wikipedia page for eigenvalue algorithms ([Eigenvalue algorithm#Iterative_algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#Iterative_algorithms)), and it appears that most algorithms work for symmetric or Hermitian matrices only.

I am actually only interested in calculating the highest eigenvalue in terms of its modulus. I have therefore tried the power iteration method, but it seems that it doesn't always converge (tried a few cases with a python script).

I would need such an algorithm for a Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD) problem where I want to calculate the highest eigenvalue of the fluid velocity gradient tensor in each cell, so the matrices are 3x3 but can be any sort of matrix (i.e. not necessarily symmetric or Hermitian, etc).

I also would like to mention that the software I would use for this calculation can't handle complex numbers. I am aware that it is very likely that two of the eigenvalues might be complex, but I only need the highest modulus of these eigenvalues.

Do you have any suggestions on an algorithm could use in my context?

Comment: further down in the wiki article is an exact method for general 3x3 matrices